# json_decode not showing data in php code

Tags: php, arrays, json

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the suggestions (what did I do to get -3? I don't understand that)

I found that the data field was set as VARCHAR and truncated the JSON off at 255 characters, making it invalid.  I changed that, and the JSON is now valid according to JSONlist.com

But it still refuses to chow, so at the risk of getting more demerits, here is the current code, is there anything I am doing wrong?

JSON:
    [{"name":"images/front_8mhztpaj.jpg","usrName":"GEDC0041.JPG","size":805229,"type":"image/jpeg","thumbnail":"images/front_8mhztpaj.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image/jpeg","thumbnail_size":10490,"searchStr":"front_8mhztpaj.jpg,!:sStrEnd"}]

New Code:

```
<?php

$json = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE"); 
//

json_decode($json, true);

?>
  <?php if ($DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE") != "") { ?> 
  <?php $imgsrc = "input/".$myImage = $myArray[0]['name']; ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="<?php echo $DETAILS->getColumnVal("TITLE"); ?>">    <?php echo $imgsrc; ?>
  <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
$DETAILS->moveNext();
}
$DETAILS->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
```

The query is still working correctly, when I ask it to echo "IMAGE" it shows the json string I have posted here, but in the page where the image data should be it just shows "input/" and no text afterwards.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid... maybe a typo... or maye is really invalid...

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ is a nice little page to help you determine if wha you've got is valid JSON or just an assortment of characters which kind of (but not really) look like JSON.

Comment: @apokryfos is right! It's a very good tool, I use it on a daily basis :) (with a preference to the 'pro' version (which is free) [pro.jsonlint.com](http://pro.jsonlint.com) )

Comment: ok... thank you so much for all your answers! I have taken them on board. I hope this is the right place to answer?

Comment: From your comments I found that the data field that was storing the json was a varchar field, truncating at 255 characters, and the length of the string meant it was truncated.  I changed that to a text field, and then reintroduced a correct json code, tested in JSONlint - but still no image shows up! Tearing my hair out! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided is misformated, there's missing closing tags. Seems the backslashes are mandatory, you can remove them if you have no need to escape your paths. (*@alex-t*)

Also, a good practice is to avoid PHP opening/closing tags in the middle of your code. That'll make it less messy.

```
<?php

$json = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("IMAGE");

// Stripslashes() is mandatory
$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($json), true);

// Security check in case json_decode returns false.
if ($myArray) {
    $myImage = $myArray[0]["name"];
    $myTitle = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("TITLE");

    // Into a double quoted string, you can 'inject' php vars.
    // just put it like $myVar or wrap it with {$myVar}
    echo "<img src=\"input/{$myImage}\" class=\"img-responsive center-block\" alt=\"{$myTitle}\">";
}
```

Comment: The backslashes to escape forward slashes are not useless, they are just not necessary in this case. They do have some point in being there and it's best to keep them in.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I used stripslashes() as a basic 'clean code' concern. It's better to know when you read the code that your path may contain escaped slashes imo.

Comment: It may cause a problem if (for some reason) you have a string value somewhere in there that reads `"</script>"` and you're using this JSON inside a `<script>` block.

Comment: Absolutly right. But it seems that this JSON data block isn't suited to contain some html tags.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The main issue I had (thanks to you guys) was that the data field containing the JSON was set as a VARCHAR, and truncated to 255 characters.

The secondary issue I had was a php error

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

should have read:

```
$myArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Thanks to all who helped

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove the slashes from the JSON string first:

```
$myArray = json_decode(stripslashes($json), true);
```